# Selenium scripts gets failed in jenkins but works fine in local

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

My selenium java scripts are running fine in local but gets failed in jenkins. For example:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='IDName']")).click();//loads a new page
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='TextBox']"))).sendKeys("xyz");
```

After running scripts like this in jenkins am getting error as `Unable to locate element: "//div[@id='TextBox']"`. But when I run same script again in jenkins it gets passed. I can understand this is due to the page is not loading properly. Am using the following command in base class.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//_TIMEOUT = 50;
```

I can add `Thread.sleep()` or `driver.wait()` between the click and sendkeys lines, but I don't think its a good idea since I have more than 600 scripts to execute.

Comment: Are you doing any Ajax calls?

Comment: No I am not using any Ajax calls..

Comment: Needs way more information. What version of Jenkins? What browser? What version of that browser? If Chrome, what version of the Chrome Driver? Have you taken a screenshot upon failure to see *exactly* where it is when it fails?

Comment: Jenkins version 1.505, firefox 19.0.2, drivers - most recent versions, running in linux machine. always getting errors in the next line of command which loads a page.

Answer (score 0):

Add implicit wait, to make sure the element is already available, or use sleep

Answer (score 0):

WebdriverWait is probably what you need.

Here is a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9904784/629116

You'll want to wait for "//div[@id='TextBox']" to be rendered before you attempt to sendKeys to it.  You also might want to consider using css selectors instead of xpath when possible.  I've found that the css selectors are found faster and can generally withstand changes to the DOM because of their flexibility.